# Promises not resolving as expected

Tags: javascript, promise

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to make my promises work. In my main code block I use:

```
this.services.city.get(this.game.player.id, this.game.player.realm).then((cities) => {
    console.log('core', cities);
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

and the get method in my city service:

```
get(owner, realm){
    var _t = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var cities = [];
        var query = 'SELECT * FROM cities WHERE owner = '+owner+' AND realm = '+realm;
        _t.core.db.query(query).then((results) => {
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                var data = {
                    id: results[i].id,
                    name: results[i].name,
                    owner: results[i].owner,
                    age: results[i].age,
                    x: results[i].x,
                    y: results[i].y,
                    realm: results[i].realm,
                    food: results[i].food,
                    wood: results[i].wood,
                    stone: results[i].stone,
                    ore: results[i].ore,
                    gold: results[i].gold,
                    population: results[i].population,
                    buildings: {}
                };
                var city = CityModel(data);
                Promise.all([_t.getCurrentBuilds(city.id), _t.getCityBuildings(city.id), _t.getFieldBuildings(city.id)]).then((values) => {
                    city.currentBuilds = values[0];
                    city.buildings.city = values[1];
                    city.buildings.field = values[2];
                    console.log('city', city);
                    cities.push(city);
                });
            }
            resolve(cities);
        }).catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

The output from `console.log('city', city);` displays the data I need, however, `console.log('core', cities);` is an empty array. How can I wait for the get method's loop to finish and the other promises to resolve before resolving the whole array of cities?

Comment: You aren't waiting for your `Promise.all()` to finish before `resolve(cities)` is called.  There are lots of things wrong here.  You're using an anti-pattern to wrap all this in another manually created promise (you can just use the promises you already have) and you need to chain your `Promise.all()` to the parent promises.  And, you need to accumulate the loop promises in an array and use `Promise.all()` on them.  Or, change to sequential implementation and use `async/await`.

Comment: @jfriend00 could you provide a short example of how to accomplish this in the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't waiting for your `Promise.all()` to finish before `resolve(cities)` is called. There are lots of things wrong here. You're using an anti-pattern to wrap all this in another manually created promise (you can just use the promises you already have) and you need to chain your `Promise.all()` to the parent promises. And, you need to accumulate the loop promises in an array and use `Promise.all()` on them. Or, change to sequential implementation and use `async/await`.

Here's a fixed up version:

```
get(owner, realm) {
    const _t = this;
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM cities WHERE owner = ' + owner + ' AND realm = ' + realm;
    return _t.core.db.query(query).then((results) => {
        const promises = [];
        for (let result of results) {
            const data = {
                id: result.id,
                name: result.name,
                owner: result.owner,
                age: result.age,
                x: result.x,
                y: result.y,
                realm: result.realm,
                food: result.food,
                wood: result.wood,
                stone: result.stone,
                ore: result.ore,
                gold: result.gold,
                population: result.population,
                buildings: {}
            };
            const city = CityModel(data);
            const p = Promise.all([
                _t.getCurrentBuilds(city.id),
                _t.getCityBuildings(city.id),
                _t.getFieldBuildings(city.id)
            ]).then((values) => {
                city.currentBuilds = values[0];
                city.buildings.city = values[1];
                city.buildings.field = values[2];
                console.log('city', city);
                return city;
            });
            promises.push(p);
        }
        // collect all the city objects from their promises
        return Promise.all(promises);
    });
}
```

Since I can't run/test this code, there could be some typos in here, but hopefully you can see the core structure and make any fixes that are required.

Major changes:

1. Return the top level promise from the function and chain everything else onto that to eliminate the anti-pattern of wrapping an existing promise in a manually created promise.  Besides making the asynchronous flow works, your code was missing all sorts of error handling paths that failed to propagate errors back to the caller.
2. Collect the result of the `Promise.all()` in the `for` loop into an array so we can use `Promise.all()` on that array of promises to know when everything is done.
3. Do `return city` inside the inner `Promise.all()` so it becomes the resolved value of that promise and we can track it in order as part of the `Promise.all()` result rather than pushing it into a higher scoped array.
4. Add `Promise.all()` to track the results of the `for` loop and collect all the cities and return that from the `.then()` handler to chain it.
5. Get rid of `var` everywhere.  You should not be programming with `var` any more.  `const` and `let` are more appropriate in modern Javascript.

---

Here's a little simpler version that uses some `async/await`, but still preserves the parallel execution of the individual city queries:

```
async get(owner, realm) {
    const _t = this;
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM cities WHERE owner = ' + owner + ' AND realm = ' + realm;
    const results = await _t.core.db.query(query);
    return Promise.all(results.map(async result => {
        const data = {
            id: result.id,
            name: result.name,
            owner: result.owner,
            age: result.age,
            x: result.x,
            y: result.y,
            realm: result.realm,
            food: result.food,
            wood: result.wood,
            stone: result.stone,
            ore: result.ore,
            gold: result.gold,
            population: result.population,
            buildings: {}
        };
        const city = CityModel(data);
        const values = await Promise.all([
            _t.getCurrentBuilds(city.id),
            _t.getCityBuildings(city.id),
            _t.getFieldBuildings(city.id)
        ]);
        city.currentBuilds = values[0];
        city.buildings.city = values[1];
        city.buildings.field = values[2];
        console.log('city', city);
        return city;
    });
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the explanation!